# How can I determine the sudo password?

Tags: sudo

[image: what is the default password of the sudo??, i visit some forums, it tells that the default password is password, but it doesn't work, how can i determine the password??]

What is the default password of the `sudo`? I visit some forums, it tells that the default password is password, but it doesn't work, how can I determine the password?

Comment: The password is same as you have given while installation. You are a sudo user, it is asking your password not root password.

Comment: I think we should reopen this, as it's not asking how to reset the password, but instead what password to use. Many people new to Ubuntu don't know that the password for `sudo` is just their own password.

Comment: Haven't you guys consider that Ubuntu may have come preinstalled?

Comment: Hello I have daemon issue. My python script is fine in terminal but failed in symfony framewrok. Please help me

Answer (score 19):

There is no default password for `sudo`.  The password that is being asked,   is the same password that you set when you installed Ubuntu - the one you use to login.

Comment: Hello I have daemon issue. My python script is fine in terminal but failed in symfony framewrok. Please help me

Comment: Even when I enter the correct password it still keeps on displaying 'Sorry try again'.

Answer (score 10):

Sudo is asking for the user's password it's called with. In your case the password in question is the password of the user `genz`, hence it says `[sudo] password for genz:`

Answer (score 6):

As has been pointed out by other answers there is no default **sudo** password.  When you installed Ubuntu you were asked for a password it is the one you created then that you need.

The computer does not store the password anywhere but a hash value created from it; when you type a password a hash value is calculated and this is compared to the hash stored from the correct password.

This makes it very difficult to find the password.

If you have lost the password you can reset it however.  See This question

[How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/q/24006/107450)

Answer (score 6):

By default the root account is disabled, therefore there is no password for it.

If you want to run a command with root privileges simply prefix it with 'sudo', it will ask you for the password to the account you are logged in with (not the root account). Assuming that account is an administrator, of course.

If you want to elevate that entire command session to root privileges type 'sudo su', you will still need to enter the password to your account.

Comment: I was going crazy until I came across this tip.

Answer (score 2):

Sudo password is the password that you put in the instalation of ubuntu/yours user password, if you don't have a password just click enter at all. Thats easy probaly you need to be an administrator user for using sudo.

Sorry for the spelling

Comment: Lifesaver! Thanks for saving me a few hours.