# Trying to compile/install gnuradio

Tags: command-line

```
john@john-Latitude-E6420:~$ sudo apt-get install gnuradio
[sudo] password for john:
```

Total Linux newbie.  What is wanted for `[sudo] password for john`?

Comment: This is the password you use at the login screen (i.e., the password for user `john`).

Comment: Please note that, for security reasons, the password is not echoed back; not even ****. Just type it in and press `Enter.`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine the sudo password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/297046/how-can-i-determine-the-sudo-password)

Answer (score 1):

your password that you use to login.
as you type it will appear blank. 
just type it anyway and hit enter.

resources on 'sudo'

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

its a tedious read but will inform you well on what sudo/root is and what it can do for you