# Getting "you need to grant administrative rights to install software" when attempting to install software

Tags: password, chromebook

I've been getting the above message every time I want to install any software from a "unknown source." I don't know what my admin password is. How do I set up a password or what is my password supposed to be. I am using a chromebook.

Comment: Is this Ubuntu installed on a ChromeBook or Chrome OS you are having issues with?

Comment: It's your user password: http://askubuntu.com/questions/297046/how-can-i-determine-the-sudo-password

Comment: Also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple: you can ONLY install new software if you are the admin. Or you know the password, or you don't install it. Security, you know?