# What is the default password for system changes in 16.04 desktop?

Tags: 16.04

I'm a newbie. Just installed Ubuntu 16.04 desktop onto my HP laptop. I need a password to make any changes to system settings. Is there a default password? If so what is it?

Comment: Your user password is also your administrative password: http://askubuntu.com/questions/297046/how-can-i-determine-the-sudo-password

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry for the stupid newbie question. I'm new to Linux, but not new to computers. Just newly come from the dark-side to the light.