# Lecture from the local System Administrator

Tags: command-line, password, security, root

I typed the command in the `Ubuntu` console:

```
$ sudo mc
```

It returned me this:

```
We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.
```

And asks for a password. What is it? I just want to get `root` access to the console.

Comment: Type your password and you will be root!

Comment: To know more see, for example, https://serverfault.com/questions/302941/changing-the-sudo-warning

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I determine the sudo password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297046/how-can-i-determine-the-sudo-password)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. The message you got is the usual message displayed when you run "sudo" for a very first time on a given account. Consider it some kind of a warning, that you will be acting as root from now on, so you could damage the system if you make a mistake.
   It won't be displayed on subsequent invocations of "sudo".
2. The password you have to type is the password of the user you are running "sudo" from.

Comment: NOTE: The password will not show up when you type, it'll show now response to you typing in your password, but I guarantee you **the password is being entered**.  The lack of input response doesn't mean anything in this case.

Comment: *displayed when you run "sudo" for a very first time on a given account* In my case, the message was re-displayed when I upgraded `sudo`.

Comment: @ynn maybe upgrade removed the flag file indicating that the message has already been displayed. It shouldn't been so, as the file is in your home directory and upgrade shouldn't touch it. But a bug in upgrade script is always possible.